# How to put Network places and My computer icon on Fluxbox desktop

Tags: gnome, desktop, nautilus, icons, fluxbox

I'm getting used to Fluxbox and it is great... I configured everything (icons, keys...) but I have this problem... I can't manage to put my Netowork places and Computer icons on desktop because I don't know their location in folder hierarchy. I supposed they are handled by Nautilus (I use Fedora 15, gnome 3 env.) and I use this workaround by starting nautilus (without the --no-desktop flag) and I get these icons on desktop... but I was wondering is there a way to integrate these into fluxbox Idesk desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no.

there is no "fluxbox idesk desktop". they are separate programs (even projects).

so, using `nautilus` is not a workaround, it is the way to achieve this.

Comment: Oh sorry for my ignorance